# mysql update a cell C with the updated division of cell A and B

Tags: mysql

I got a cell in my table called platform_rating which shall be the percentual 
value of of the division of two other cells (platform_likes / total_votes)*100. Whenever somebody clicks the like button, 'platform_likes', 'total_votes' are updated but 'platform_rating' is not. Here is the row in the array:

```
<?php

'platform_rating' => ($row['total_votes'] != 0) ?  ($row['platform_likes'] / 
$row['total_votes'])*100 : 0,

?>
```

and here is the function to update:

```
<?php

function add_like($platform_id)
{
$platform_id = (int)$platform_id;
mysql_query("UPDATE `flights` SET `platform_likes` = `platform_likes` + 1,
`total_votes` = `total_votes` + 1, **`platform_rating` =  
`platform_rating`((platform_likes / total_votes)*100)** WHERE platform_id = 
$platform_id");
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have `platform_rating` twice in that update query? Ignoring division by zero errors for a sec, shouldn't that read `platform_rating = ((platform_likes / total_votes)*100)`?

Comment: You're welcome! I've posted my comment as an answer - if this helped, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're multiplying the percentage by `platform_rating` because of a stray `platform_rating` in your UPDATE query. It should read platform_rating = ((platform_likes / total_votes)*100)